# How to swap main image with elevateZoom with <select><option> not with <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

in my website i use elevateZoom to show and zoom list of images.

```
<a href="#" data-image="<?php echo $thumb; ?>"
      data-zoom-image="<?php echo $popup; ?>">
     <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" alt=""/>
</a>
```

I want to do same but with `<select>`

I try to change in jquery.elevatezoom.js  `' a'` with `' option'` but this work only on firefox, in other browsers not work

```
        //Create the image swap from the gallery 
        $('#'+self.options.gallery + ' a').click( function(e) { 

            //Set a class on the currently active gallery image
            if(self.options.galleryActiveClass){
                $('#'+self.options.gallery + ' a').removeClass(self.options.galleryActiveClass);
                $(this).addClass(self.options.galleryActiveClass);
            }
            //stop any link on the a tag from working
            e.preventDefault();

            //call the swap image function            
            if($(this).data("zoom-image")){self.zoomImagePre = $(this).data("zoom-image")}
            else{self.zoomImagePre = $(this).data("image");}
            self.swaptheimage($(this).data("image"), self.zoomImagePre);

        });
```

Thank for help in advance